# Using 'awk' to store specific line numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, awk

I have a destination.properties file:

```
Port:22
10.52.16.156
10.52.16.157
10.52.16.158
10.52.16.159
10.52.16.160
10.52.16.161
10.52.16.162
10.52.16.163
10.52.16.164
10.52.16.165
10.52.16.166
10.52.16.167
10.52.16.168
10.52.16.169


Port:61900-61999
10.52.16.156
10.52.16.157
10.52.16.158
10.52.16.159
10.52.16.160
10.52.16.161
10.52.16.162
10.52.16.163
10.52.16.164
10.52.16.165
10.52.16.166
10.52.16.167
10.52.16.168
10.52.16.169
```

I want to use an awk command to store all of the line numbers of lines that contain the word 'Port:' in an array.

I have the following command which stores all of the line numbers in the 1st array value ie array[0]:

```
array=$( (awk '/Port:/ {print NR}' destinations.prop) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get them in a shell array, you can do:

```
array=( $(awk '/Port:/ {print NR}' destinations.prop) )
```

The parenthesis assign the words within to successive array members. As usual, `IFS` controls the splitting of that command output, and file name globbing also happens if you happen to output wildcard characters. Probably not an issue in this case.